# Moving element from another container using appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying this out for almost an hour and I can't seem to figureout where did I made a mistake. I'm trying to move "total_row" to "tfoot" element. that way it should looke like this

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>250</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>350</td>
    </tr>
<tfoot>
```

MY code:

```
$cur_table = $("#wrap_table");

$total_row = $cur_table.find("tr:not(:eq(0)) td:contains('Total')").parent();

$total_row.parent().after('<tfoot></tfoot>');

$total_row.appendTo($cur_table.find("tfoot"));
```

Thank You!

Comment: do you have a quick jsfiddle so we have a "working" thing to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```js
$cur_table = $("#wrap_table");

$total_row = $cur_table.find("tr:not(:eq(0)) td:contains('Total')").parent();

var $tfoot = $('<tfoot></tfoot>').insertAfter($total_row.parent());

$total_row.appendTo($tfoot);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}
tbody {
  background-color: red;
}
tfoot {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="wrap_table">
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>250</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>350</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : find the first `td` containing 'Total' (remove single quotes) and append to `tfoot`

```
var $cur_table = $("#wrap_table");

var $total_row = $cur_table.find("td:contains(Total):first").closest('tr');

$total_row.appendTo($cur_table.find("tfoot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is probably better idea. You should set a class or id to your total row so markup becomes like this:

```
<tr class="total-row">
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>250</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>350</td>
</tr>
```

Then javascript can be:

```
var $curTable = $("#wrap_table");
var $totalRow = $curTable.find(".total-row");

$('<tfoot></tfoot>').insertAfter($totalRow.parent()).append($totalRow);
```

There is a huge benefit of such approach. First of all your JS code does not depend on text in HTML. With your approach (selecting by word "Total") you will have to change javacript every time you change text. It will also not work if you localize your app.

Not to mention, with class name it's much simpler to style "Total row" with individual styles.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, but unfortunately I can't change the DOM and add a class on an element, So I have to resort on this crud way.